# Stop sendmail rejecting user's emails when LDAP server is unreachable

Tags: ldap, sendmail, openldap

I have a sendmail inbound mail server that accepts emails delivered to local users. The local user database comes from LDAP using nss_ldapd. Occasionally the LDAP server is unreachable/down, and in that case, sendmail permanently rejects mail to recipients (500 5.1.1 .... user unknown)

I'd prefer it didn't - for example by giving a temporary error.

Is there an easy solution to make this happen?

Comment: Which sendmail map is server by LDAP lookups? [virtusertable, ldpap_routing maps, ...]

Comment: The unix-level passwd database is being served from LDAP.

Comment: You may ask your question `at news:comp.mail.sendmail`.

Comment: you could create local maps based on ldap information, updating them on a regular basis. That way users would be local, but the info would come from ldap. That would require some scripting, though.